# Spring Web application not running

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a spring web application build with maven. If i run that through Netbean it runs but if i simple copy `.war` in `webapps` folder it doesn't run.

Here is `context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/myapp"/>
```

`web.xml`

```
<display-name>myapp</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>        
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is the directory structure

```
 myapp
   |-----------META-INF
   |-----------resources
   |-----------Web-inf
```

Through Netbean i can run `localhost:8084/myapp` but if i just copy .war file to webapps folder i can't

Comment: Are there any message in container logs, are are other application from same container (tomcat often has docs or a root application) accessible ?

Comment: Silly question but when you deploy via IDE it usually restarts/redeploys the server. When you do it manually people usually forget and thus server doesn't pick up some changes. Can you give that a go?

Comment: if i access the page of tomcat it is accessible